Jetpack Glance: Add Linear Gradient to a Box Composable
I like to add a linear gradient to a Glance composable but it seems like there is no brush I can add like in Jetpack.
Box(
  modifier = GlanceModifier
    .background(//HERE)
    .fillMaxHeight()
    .cornerRadius(16.dp)
) {}

These are the constructors that are defined for background
GlanceModifier.background(Color) defined in androidx.glance
GlanceModifier.background(ImageProvider, ContentScale = ..., ColorFilter? = ...) defined in androidx.glance
GlanceModifier.background(ColorProvider) defined in androidx.glance
GlanceModifier.background(Int) defined in androidx.glance


Glance is missing a lot of the regular Compose stuff because everything has to be translated into RemoteViews. There is no direct method in RemoteViews for setting a Shader on anything, so there's no straightforward way to do it in Glance. I'm pretty sure you'll have to either draw the gradient to a Bitmap manually and pass it through an ImageProvider, or define it in a drawable resource and apply it in a layout that's used with AndroidRemoteViews().

Thanks for the fast answer :) That helped me

I managed to implement it by using a Bitmap that I generate like Mike M. suggested.
private fun createGradientBitmap(
    width: Int,
    height: Int,
    startColor: Int,
    endColor: Int
): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    val paint = Paint()
    
    val gradient = LinearGradient(
        0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), 0f,
        startColor, endColor,
        Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
    )
    
    paint.shader = gradient
    canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), paint)
    return bitmap
}

//...
@Composable
fun Gradient(
    modifier: GlanceModifier = GlanceModifier,
) { 
Box(
    modifier = GlanceModifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .background(ImageProvider(gradientBitmap))
   ) {}
}

